# Lubricants for dissimilar metals

Tags: materials, tribology

We are trying to maintain a Grubb telescope built in 1875. We think that the bearing surfaces are either brass to brass or brass to cast iron. Can anyone help with types of lubricants that could be used in either circumstance.

Comment: Brass to iron sounds like it was intended to have the brass replaced after some time.  I'd use white lithium grease as a lubricant.

Comment: What lubricants existed in 1875?

Comment: More likely bronze for old equipment ( stronger). Base metals no problem. Use EP ( extreme pressure) lubes , Usually contain MoS.